# Understanding estimation for $\Vert (1-\Pi)F\Vert$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.15622.pdf), page 6.

Can somebody explain to me, why line (16),

$\Vert A F\Vert\leq\frac{1}{2}\Vert (1-\Pi)F\Vert$

implies that
$$
\vert\langle A(F-F_\infty),F-F_\infty\rangle\vert\leq\frac{1}{2}\Vert F-F_\infty\Vert^2?
$$

Here, for $F=(f_1,f_2)$, $\Pi$ is the projection
$$
\Pi F=\begin{pmatrix}\rho_1\chi_1\\\rho_2\chi_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

By Cauchy-Schwartz,
$$
\vert\langle A(F-F_\infty),F-F_\infty\rangle\vert\leq\Vert A(F-F_\infty)\Vert\cdot\Vert F-F_\infty\Vert
$$

That means that I need to show that
$$
\Vert A(F-F_\infty)\Vert\leq \frac{1}{2}\Vert F-F_\infty\Vert.
$$

I did not understand why, but it seems to be that $AF_{\infty}=0$, so that with (16)
$$
\Vert A(F-F_\infty)\Vert=\Vert AF\Vert\leq\frac{1}{2}\Vert (1-\Pi)F\Vert
$$

So, I guess my question boils down see why
$$
\Vert (1-\Pi)F\Vert\leq\Vert F-F_\infty\Vert.
$$

Heuristically, my explanation would be the following:

Since $F_\infty=(f_{1,\infty},f_{2,\infty})$ with $f_{1,\infty}=\rho_{1,\infty}\chi_1$ and $f_{2,\infty}=\rho_{2,\infty}\chi_2$, I guess that
$\Pi F_\infty=F_\infty$ so that
$$
\Vert (1-\Pi)F\Vert=\Vert F-\Pi F\Vert\leq\Vert F-\Pi F_\infty\Vert=\Vert F-F_\infty\Vert
$$
for all $F=(f_1,f_2)$, because $F_\infty$ maximizes the distance $\Vert F-\Pi F\Vert$ with respect to $\Pi F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your Cauchy-Schwarz, you just have to apply $(16)$ with $F$ replaced by $F-F_\infty$, and then use the fact that as an operator $0\leq 1-\Pi\leq 1$.

Comment: Why can I apply (16) for $F-F_\infty$? Why is $0\leq 1-\Pi\leq 1$? Both is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: Isn't $\Pi$ an orthogonal projection, so that the operator norm of $I-\Pi$ is equal to $1$? Maybe this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it was an inequality in the sense of operators. It is indeed equivalent to say that it is a positive operator with operator norm smaller than $1$

Comment: You can apply (16) to any function $F$, so in particular to $F-F_\infty$

Comment: Could you please explain to me why the operator norm of $1-\Pi$ is smaller than $1$? I do not see it. I don't think that $1-\Pi$ is orthogonal.

Comment: It is orthogonal for the scalar product defined in p.5.